# time complexity for following function

Tags: c#, optimization, time-complexity

Can any tell the time complexity of following block of code

```
private static void Multiply(int num1, int num2)
{           
        long p,b,h1,h2,l1,l2,z0,z1,z2,m1,m2;
        p = num1.ToString().Length-2;
         b=Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10,Convert.ToDouble(p)));
        l1=num1%b;
        h1 = num1 - l1;
        l2 = num2 % b;
        h2 = num2 - l2;
        m1=num1 / b;
        m2=num2 / b;
        z0 =  l1*(m1+m2);
        z1 = m1*(h2 + Math.Abs(l1 - l2));
        z2=l1*l2;
        Console.WriteLine("Result is :"+((z0 +z1)*b+z2));
        Console.ReadLine();            
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. _time complexity_ on what exactly? Can you please clarify your question? What is your problem? What is your variables? What is your result values and what values you expected actually? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: actually it is multiplication of two large numbers the num1 ,num2 take numbers as input  and result is display on console .so I want to know what is time complexity for above function

Comment: If you are looking for big-O notation, I believe this is O(1), since the complexity is not determined by the amount of data input into the algorithm. That is, the algorithm will take a specific amount of time no matter what is passed in for the two input variables. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upto my knowledge, most common time complexity notation is Big-O, I'll share same in this answer. Time complexity is `O(1)`, with an assumption that `Math.Pow` calculation is `O(1)` and `.ToString()` method is `O(1)`. It is `O(1)` because each step will be executed only once.

In gerenal, if we take `.ToString().Length` time complexity into account then it would be `O(length of num1)` because conversion from `int` to `String` will take `O(length of num1)` or `O(number of digits)`. But as we are dealing with `int`, which will atmost have 11 digits, which is constant, we can say time complexity is `O(1)`.

Comment: Note: `string.Length` by itself is O(1) (the length is stored with the string)

Comment: That's nice, I thought it will be calculated dynamically when we call `length`. But when you convert a integer to String and then call `length`, will it still be `O(1)`?

Comment: The conversion from int to string itself will be O(N) where N is the number of digits in the number (when written in decimal).

Comment: So, `O(length of num1)` holds. Modifying answer from lenth complexity to conversion time complexity :)

Comment: Technically, but you wouldn't normally factor that into the complexity for the OP's code, since N is going to at most 11 (including minus sign); it is not helpful for determining complexity, and indeed is misleading. Think of it this way: If you plot a graph of time taken against the value of `num1` or `num2` would it be a horizontal line? Yes, it would (to all intents and purposes). Therefore it's O(1)

Comment: Ok. got it. As it is `int`, we can say it as constant. If user tends to use `BigInteger` or something like that then we will have to consider it. Modifying answeer according. Thanks :)